# Unity WebGL Download normal map texture from server using www

Tags: textures, unityscript, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I'm developing a WebGL program with Unity 5.3.1

```
    WWW www = new WWW(System.Uri.EscapeUriString(nrmUrl));
    while (!www.isDone)
    {
        yield return null;
    }
    materailBall.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetTexture("_BumpMap", www.texture);
```

And the result is

[image]

It seems that the property texture type is **Texture**

Please help me to change texture type of this nrm image to **Normal map**

Is there some good ideal to download normal map texture?

Or someone can tell me how to use **TextureImporter** with **www**?

Thanks!!

**Supplement:**

If I create material with local file, here is the different

**Texture type : Texture**

[image]

**Texture type : Normal map**

[image]

Comment: Few questions or you. What problems are you having now? It looks like you are using customized shader...Why can't you use standard shader?

Comment: Same problem with standard shader. I want to download a image and set it as bump map. But the texture type I down is default texture.

Comment: @siusiulala can you check this answer: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/47121/runtime-normal-map-import.html ?

Comment: @JerrySwitalski That's what i need. It solves my problem. Thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 0):

To use named shaders variants how "_BumpMap" you need this material must be in used in the scene or in the Resource Folder.